# How shall I print caller object name inside a class member function?

Tags: c++

See the example

```
  class MyClass {
    public:
    void fn() {
            // Here  I want to print caller object name,( here it is  ***it1***)
        }
    };


    int main() {
        MyClass it1;
        it1.fn();
        return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: You can't. At most you can do `typeid(*this).name()`, which will give an *implementation-defined name of the **type*** `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The instance's variable name is not available mainly due to two reasons:

1. It is no business of the called function, so it can't be accessed. The whole point of procedural programming is *not* accessing the calling context through anything but the formal parameters.
2. The variable names have no effect on the final program. It shouldn't and doesn't matter whether you call your variable it1, foo or even treat it anonymously.

Or, in short terms: If `fn()` would be const, you could call it with a temporary:

```
MyClass().fn();
```

What would be your answer then? What for an array of MyClass objects? Variable names determine which functions to call, not how these functions work.